# Assigning values of the response object to the model object

Tags: angular

I have implemented a service method in angular that calls asp.net webapi that returns an integer array via the response object. I need capture those values as part of the model object and pass it to another endpoint call called getDocumentUploadDetailsByIds.  I initially tried to pass the values directly to my endpoint but it was  null when hitting the breakpoint. So I decided to pass the array as part of the array object. How do I assign the values to the models ids array. Could somebody tell me how do I achieve that.

```
export interface IDocumentIds {
  ids: number[];
}


   documentIds: IDocumentIds;

    this.documentUploadService.createDocumentUpload(this.documents)
                .then((result) => {
                    if (result) {
                        //this.documentIds.ids = result;
                        this.getDocumentUploadDetailsByIds(result);
                        this.setGridOptions();
                        this.setColumns();
                        this.notify.success('Documents uploaded Successfully');
                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    this.notify.error('An Error Has Occured While uploading the documents');
                });
```

Comment: `this.documentUploadService.createDocumentUpload` method returns a promise or an Observable?

Comment: It returns a promise

Comment: You can do this - `documentIds: IDocumentIds = <IDocumentIds>{};` and then assign `this.documentIds.ids = result;`

Comment: I am getting error message error TS2322: Type 'Response' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
  Property 'length' is missing in type 'Response'.

Comment: Post your response, please. I mean what `result` logs i.e. `console.log(result)`.

Comment: Sure . I shall but the above error is compile time

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196112/discussion-between-user2216584-and-tom).